# How can I use Angular4 without npm lite-server?

Tags: angular, npm, lite-server

I'm using Angular 4 for my project.
Here my scenario is to use Angular 4 without any server(even npm lite-server).

**These are the steps which I followed to test the project without any server.**
- Built the app using "ng build --prod", to get the compiled file in dist folder.
- Compiled successfully
- now I moved to dist folder and opend the index.html in browser, but now my anuglar 4 app wasn't working
- But it is working fine, if I execute "ng server" command,which start the npm lite-server.

**My requirement is, I want use Angular 4 app without starting any server.**

Comment: You will need to have a static content server, you can use nginx or apache. Those are the most popular ones.

Comment: in this case, what web server do you use  !

Comment: you want to run it just by double clicking the `index.html` file?

Comment: I planned to use nginix. But,my backend is running with django server for time being. Is it possible to serve angular with django server itself.@AnouarMokhtari

Comment: yes I do it with Pyramid , if you want to use your server back-end to serve the view front-end.
you have to renderer you index.html

renderer='index.html'

Comment: thanks a lot.. its going good with nginx server...